# fetching all the call details like number,call type etc after call disconnect and automatically post it with web services

Tags: android, web-services, calllog

I have fetched all the call details through this code.

```
  private void getCallDetails() {


    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Cursor managedCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC LIMIT 40");
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);


            //  sb.append("Call Details :");
    String finalDate[];
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String durationn=managedCursor.getString(duration);
        System.out.println("Ph No....."+ phNumber);
        System.out.println("Type....."+callType);
        System.out.println("DAte....."+ callDate);
        System.out.println("Duration....."+ callDayTime);



        System.out.println("Call date time is "+callDayTime);
        String calldatechange=callDayTime.toString();
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }

            phnoList.add(phNumber);
        calldura.add(durationn);
        System.out.println("call duration is"+calldura);
        //calDatList.add(callDate);
        calltimeList.add(calldatechange);



       /* forcalLog.add("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);*/
        sb.append(phNumber +","+ dir + ","+ callDayTime + ","+ callDuration);
       // sb.append("\n---------------------------------------------");
    }


    System.out.println("Myphone is::"+ phnoList.size());
    System.out.println("callDate is::"+ calDatList);
    System.out.println("calltimeList is::"+ calltimeList);

    managedCursor.close();
```

Also i have fetched the time at which the call is disconnected.I am able to show a popup at the time of call disconnect.Now i want to fetch all the details of the last call at the place where call disconnect intent is checked which has been done through broadcast receiver and append all the details in web service.How can i do that.

```
  if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
            Toast.makeText(context,"the no. is"+savedNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // onOutgoingCallStarted(context,"",callStartTime);

        }
        else
        {
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;

            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        Log.d("Testing", "Outgoing call has been disconnect");
                        intent = new Intent(context, MyCustomDialog.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        System.out.println("CAll has been        disconnect...............");
        //                            Toast.makeText(this, "CAll has been disconnect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Here i am fetching the call disconnect action.At the same time i want to send all the details through web service.

Comment: whats the problem sir?

Comment: I wan to do the task at time of call disconnect but there i am using broadcast receiver and i can't fetch data from call log using get extra or anything in broadcast receiver.

Comment: Somebody please answer it. I am not able to sort it out.